# GIT not seeing updated folder name

Tags: git

Here's my current git layout:

`git
  misc
   file.sh
  other
   file2.sh`

If I change the folder name misc to misc2 it stays as misc on GIT how do I fix that? One thing to note is that the root git folder is not my git repro only the misc and other directories are.

Comment: if `misc` is the root of the repo (`.git` subirectory inside it) it can have any name.

Answer (score 1):

try `git add -u` on parent directory of the misc folder.

```
C02J8GV9DKQ1:test chlr$ git add -u
C02J8GV9DKQ1:test chlr$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    misc/file.txt -> misc2/file.txt
```

Comment: Like I said the parent of the misc folder is not a git repro so that command doesn't work on the parent `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: can you update your question with location of the .git folders as well? this will simplify the understanding of the question